# Underscore - Filter against an array of values

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection `self.models`. I also have an array of an object which contains the fields and filters I wish to apply to my collection called `filterArr`. An example of this would be:

```
[{field: "Account", filter: "123"}, {field: "Owner", filter: "Bob"}]
```

The question is, I'm not sure quite how I'd iterate through each of my models to return only those models to which this `filterArr` applies too, I know it has to be something like this, but this is hard-coded:

```
self.models = _.filter(self.models, function (model) {
                    model = model.toJSON();
                    return model.Account === "123" && model.Owner === "Bob";

});
```

Comment: I'm not able to understand what you are trying to.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basically you need to iterate over model's attributes and compare their keys and values to filter's attributes.

```
self.models = _.filter(self.models, function (model) {
  var fits = true; // does this model "fit" the filter?
  model = model.toJSON();
  _.each(model, function(modelVal, modelKey) {
     _.each(filterArr, function(filter) {
        if (modelKey === filter.field && modelVal !== filter.filter) {
           fits = false
        }
     }
  })
  return fits
})
```

However, with a bit of underscore magic there's a trickier way. I'm not sure if it's better in terms of performance, but it surely looks better to my eye.

```
    // change a bit the way filter is described:
var filter = {Account: '123', Owner: 'Bob'},
    // save an array of filter keys (Account, Owner)
    filterKeys = _.keys(filter),
    // and an array of its values (123, Bob)
    filterVals = _.values(filter)
self.models = _.filter(self.models, function (model) {
      // pick a subset of model which has the same keys as filter
  var filteredSubset = _.pick(model.attributes, filterKeys),
      // pick values of this subset
      subsetValues = _.values(filteredSubset)
      // this values have to be equal to filter's values
      // (use .join() to turn array to string before comparison due to references)
      return filteredVals.join() === subsetValues.join()
})
```

Notice that in the latter case all models have to have all the keys declared in filter.

If I were you and I were looking for a most robust way, I would rewrite the first example, but would have changed `_.each` to standard `for` loops and return `false` as soon as first 'non-fit' value is met.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was after!

Comment: glad it helped, but make sure you take jakee's answer into consideration: all of its points are perfectly valid

Answer (score 7):

First of all, underscore's filter returns an `Array`, so what you're doing effectively here is substituting your collection with a filtered array. Something like this would be more appropriate:

```
this.filtered = _.filter(this.models, ...);
```

Backbone Collection implements most of [underscore's useful functions](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods). So the solution above is far from optimal (in fact it doesn't work at all the way you want it to), instead do something like this:

```
this.filtered = this.models.filter(function() {...});
```

The best way to get and set model fields by name are by far the `get` and `set` [functions](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) of Backbone `Model`, so why not use them? `Model.toJSON()` works, but you're just copying the `attributes`-hash unnecessarily around.

```
this.filterObj = { // Why not make it an object instead of array of objects
  "Account": "123",
  "Owner": "Bob"
};
this.filtered = this.models.filter(function(model) {
  // use the for in construct to loop the object
  for (filter in filterObj) {
    // if the model doesn't pass a filter check, then return false
    if (model.get(filter) !== filterObj[filter]) return false;
  }
  // the model passed all checks, return true
  return true;
});
```

Hope this helps!